# Custom ItemsControl does not show DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I want to implement a custom ItemsControl like this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290587/A-WPF-TileView-Control

I have 2 classes for this:

```
HeatMapView (derived from ItemsControl)
```

and

```
HeatMapItem (derived from ContentControl)
```

In HeatMapView i override 2 Methods from parent

```
static HeatMapView()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeatMapView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeatMapView)));
}


protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return item is HeatMapItem;
}

protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new HeatMapItem();
}
```

HeatMapItem has also a static constructor

```
static HeatMapItem()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeatMapItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeatMapItem)));
    }
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type heatmap:HeatMapView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type heatmap:HeatMapView}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Canvas>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type heatmap:HeatMapItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type heatmap:HeatMapItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="heatMap:HeatMapItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="heatMap:HeatMapItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border CornerRadius="5" Grid.Row="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="heatMap:HeatMapView">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button Content="{Binding Key}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <heatMap:HeatMapView ItemsSource="{Binding TestModels}" />
</Grid>
```

Nothing is shown when i start the application.
When i remove the ItemSource and add manually HeatMapItems to the HeatMapView with a Background set, i can see the items.

What´s wrong here?

Comment: When i use a ListBox with the same DataTemplate, everything works as expected

Comment: I once had the similar problem and removed this line and it worked! DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeatMapView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeatMapView)));

Comment: @Bizz When i remove this i can see that there are items in the Items Property. But Items is filled the value from databinding and not with HeatMapItems as containers

Comment: it might be the Canvas in HeatMapView style, replace it with Grid and see if it works

Comment: I pasted all your XAML and code in two new projects (a control library and a WPF app), and it works perfectly. So there must be something more that you haven't shown yet.

Comment: @Clemens You are right. I forgot to post the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods. Never tought that this could be a problem. When i remove them items will be placed in the HeatMapView. Not with my desired layout but it´s ok

Comment: @Bizz Can you tell me why DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeatMapView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeatMapView))) is bad in this situation?

Comment: Ok. You know that for changing the layout of the items in an ItemsControl you would have to set the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx) property? And I guess the Canvas in the HeatMapView ControlTemplate is redundant. Just put the ItemsPresenter directly.

Comment: I could if I knew! it was just a desperate attempt back then but it worked for me.